# How can I tell if waiting on Event has timed out?

Tags: python, events, multithreading

> > > import threading
> > >       event = threading.Event()
> > >       event.set()
> > >       print event.wait(1)
> > >           None
> > >       event.clear()
> > >       print event.wait(1)
> > >           None

So it basically returns `None` both when condition was `True` and `False`. How can I distinguish the case of timeouting from the one with no waiting at all? Meanwile, the docs say

> This method returns the internal flag
>   on exit, so it will always return True
>   except if a timeout is given and the
>   operation times out.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're missing next sentence in documentation which writes:

> Changed in version 2.7: Previously,
>   the method always returned None.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs for `threading.Event.wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading#threading.Event.wait):

> This method returns the internal flag on exit, so it will always return `True` except if a timeout is given and the operation times out.
>
> **Changed in version 2.7: Previously, the method always returned `None`.**

Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I guess most certainly not 2.7